# Skip First Line In csv_from_result() In CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, expressionengine

I'm trying to export a simple table containing only two fields `id`, `email` to a CSV file using `csv_from_result()` in CodeIgniter.

The first line of the generated CSV file contains the name of the column, but I only want the the data.

Is there any way to skip this fist line?

This is my code :

```
$query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT email FROM exp_sct_mailing_list");

$this->EE->load->dbutil();
$data = $this->EE->dbutil->csv_from_result( $query, ",", "\r\n" );

$this->EE->load->helper('download');
force_download("mailing_list.csv", $data);
exit;
```

Comment: BTW, I'm using codeigniter in expressionengine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just remove the first line like so:

```
$query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT email FROM exp_sct_mailing_list");

$this->EE->load->dbutil();
$data = ltrim(strstr($this->EE->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, ',', "\r\n"), "\r\n"));

$this->EE->load->helper('download');
force_download("mailing_list.csv", $data);
exit;
```

Here we extract only the contents after from the first CRLF `\r\n` to the end of the data. Then we left trim the CRLF out and thus have removed the first line.

Comment: I don't understand how you use csv_from_result. Can you show me how I can apply this to the code I pasted above ?

Answer (score 1):

Saddly there is no way to do pass a parameter to function `csv_from_result` and avoid the column names, but you can build your custom `csv_from_result` function based on the code of the original function an removing the undesired part:

```
/**
* Generate CSV from a query result object
*
* @param object $query Query result object
* @param string $delim Delimiter (default: ,)
* @param string $newline Newline character (default: \n)
* @param string $enclosure Enclosure (default: ")
* @return string
*/
function my_custom_csv_from_result($query, $delim = ',', $newline = "\n", $enclosure = '"')
{
if ( ! is_object($query) OR ! method_exists($query, 'list_fields'))
{
show_error('You must submit a valid result object');
}

$out = '';

// Blast through the result array and build out the rows
while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row('array'))
{
foreach ($row as $item)
{
$out .= $enclosure.str_replace($enclosure, $enclosure.$enclosure, $item).$enclosure.$delim;
}
$out = substr(rtrim($out), 0, -strlen($delim)).$newline;
}

return $out;
}
```

The code is based on the implementation of `csv_from_result` taken from here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_utility.php

Comment: I understand this might be the cleanest way to do it, but rewriting codeigniter is way over my head ! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I was able to combine it into my code. FOr those interested I handle the headers for the CSV within my model which returns a generic array and then I cycle through that in a modified version of the csv_from_result method that I added to my controller. If someone needs an example I can post it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

```
$data = array_values(array_shift($data));
```

This will remove the first row.

your code becomes:

```
$query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT email FROM exp_sct_mailing_list");

$this->EE->load->dbutil();
$data = $this->EE->dbutil->csv_from_result( $query, ",", "\r\n" );

$data = array_values(array_shift($data)); //skip the first line

$this->EE->load->helper('download');
force_download("mailing_list.csv", $data);
exit;
```

Comment: not working, show error "array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given"